# How do i capture the stdout from is a Ray actor or task

Tags: python, logging, python-logging, ray

Here, I am trying to capture all the log stdout to a steam handler, this approach doesn't work in the case of a Ray actor. This is because Ray actors run in a separate process, and the StreamHandler only captures logs from the current process. Are there any other approach to  capture logs form Ray actor/task.

```py
import logging
import ray
from ray.util import ActorPool
from io import StringIO

# Define a Ray actor that logs a message
@ray.remote
class LoggingActor:
    def log_message(self):
        logger.warning('This is a warning message from the Ray actor')

# Create a StringIO object to capture the log messages
log_stream = StringIO()

# Create a logger and add a stream handler that writes to the StringIO object
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
handler = logging.StreamHandler(log_stream)
logger.addHandler(handler)

# Create an ActorPool with a single instance of the LoggingActor
actor = LoggingActor.remote()
ray.get(actor.log_message.remote())

# Retrieve the log messages from the StringIO object
captured_output = log_stream.getvalue()
print("here -> ", captured_output,"<- end")
```

```
here ->   <- end
(LoggingActor pid=2083) This is a warning message from the Ray actor
```

StreamHandler couldn't capture  log stdout from ray actor

Answer (score 0):

all stdout of ray actor/job is already logged as file.
so, you can read them to capture.

it located under
/tmp/ray/session_latest/logs/worker-[worker_id]-[job_id]-[pid].[out|err]

you can also get worker_id, job_id from RuntimeContext

e.g)

```
import ray
ray.get_runtime_context().get_job_id()
ray.get_runtime_context().get_worker_id()
```